# How to save all html elements font size to localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am working on font accessibility where three icons are given "A-", "A", "A+" to decrease, set to default, and increase the font size of all elements on-page. The changes should be saved and when the user again visit or open another page the changed font size should render.
To increase font size I am using

```
$(document).on("click","#large",function(){
    console.log("descrease");
    $('*').each(function(){
    var k =  parseInt($(this).css('font-size')); 
    var redSize = k * 1.10 ; //here, you can give the percentage( now it is reduced to 90%)
        $(this).css('font-size',redSize);  
    }); 
});
```

To decrease font

```
$(document).on("click","#small",function(){
    console.log("descrease");
    $('*').each(function(){
    var k =  parseInt($(this).css('font-size')); 
    var redSize = k * 0.90 ; //here, you can give the percentage( now it is reduced to 90%)
        $(this).css('font-size',redSize);  
    }); 
});
```

I am saving all fonts size to localstorage on document ready as follows

```
var allFonts = [];
$('*').each(function(){
    var k =  parseInt($(this).css('font-size')); 
    /*var redSize = k * 1.10 ; //here, you can give the percentage( now it is reduced to 90%)
    $(this).css('font-size',redSize);*/  
    allFonts[$(this)] = k; 
    console.log(allFonts,"allFonts");
    localStorage.setItem("allFonts",allFonts);
});
```

To set the font size to default

```
$(document).on("click","#normal",function(){
    console.log("normal");
    var allElems = localStorage.getItem("allFonts");
    console.log(allElems);
    $(allElems).each(function(k,v){
        console.log(k);
        $(k).css("font-size",v)  // Not working
    });
});
```

But the font size in localStorage is not saved correctly. I tried to check the value of "allFonts" which is getting generated on document ready. is showing as

```
[[object Object]: 14]
[object Object]: 14
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Please suggest me the correct way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` stores **strings**, not arrays. To store structured data (like arrays) in `localStorage`, use JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem("allFonts", JSON.stringify(allFonts));
```

...and

```
allFonts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allFonts")) || [];
```

The reason for the `|| []` on that is that when you call `getItem` and the item isn't there, you get back `null`. If you pass `null` into `JSON.parse`, it gets converted to the string `"null"` (because `parse` requires a string) and then parsed into `null`, so that's the return value of `JSON.parse`. `|| []` gives you a blank array in that case. You can also write it like this:

```
allFonts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allFonts") || "[]");
```

Answer (score 0):

to set all fonts :`localStorage.setItem("allFonts", JSON.stringify(allFonts));` 
to retrive :   `allFonts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allFonts"))`